# NumPy module not found after install

Tags: python, numpy

So after numerous attempts at installing NumPy, all seem to have gone well until I boot up PyCharm and import numpy. It throws the "Module not found" error with just a single line of code, being:

```
import numpy as numpy
```

It's getting fairly frustrating, after installing numpy through pip, downloading the .whl and manually installing it, and even somehow bricking my computer by repairing python 3.6. I've got no idea as to what I'm doing wrong. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use anaconda python distribution

Comment: PyCharm can be using a virtual environment. Go to File/Settings/Project/Interpreter and check which Python version you are using. It will list all the packages available as well.

Comment: Do you have different versions of Python on your machine?

Comment: @DavidG No, I used to but I have since removed the duplicate copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing exactly what you have installed in your computer, it can be a bit tricky to troubleshoot it. However, you have to be aware that you can have multiple Python installations in your computer. It is quite common to have Python2.X and Python3.X side by side.

When you used pip to install numpy, you installed it for a specific Python interpreter (sometimes you have pip2 and pip3 in your system, for example). And then, when you use PyCharm, it may be grabbing the wrong Python interpreter. You can go to File/Settings/Project and you will find something like the window below:

[image]

You will see that you can choose your interpreter and it will give you the list of all installed packages. I suggest that you check that you have numpy listed.

Moreover, from the same window you can install the packages you need; just click on the green + sign at the right of the screen and search for numpy and follow the needed steps.

**Pro Tip**: You should definitely consider using [virtual environments](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/how-to-use-python-virtualenv/), which are entirely supported by PyCharm.

Comment: Sure enough, it was locking itself into a virtual environment and the packages weren't going through. After navigating some menus, I found the option to install numpy for the specific project I'm running. Thanks a ton, my guy